# document.getElementById returning null even if the id is present

Tags: reactjs

`document.getElementById` is returning null even if the id is present. I am not getting what's wrong with my code.

```
optionsChange() {
  let test = document.getElementById("filterOptions");
  let opVal= test.options[test.selectedIndex].text;
  console.log("options...", opVal);
}
```

Following code is written in `render` method

```
<select
  type="text"
  className="form-control"
  name="filterOptions"
  id="filterOptions"
  onChange={this.optionsChange()}
>
  <option key="select" value="allValues">All Values</option>
  {this.renderFilterOptions(item)}
</select>
```

Can someone help please any guide me..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use `getElementById`. You could use the `event` object to get the element. The `onChange` event will pass event object by default.

> Please note Always avoid access dom objects directly in react

**Example:**

```
optiobjectonsChange(event) {
    let test = event.target;
    let opVal = test.options[test.selectedIndex].text;
    console.log("options...", opVal);
}
```

And also don't call the function in onchange, pass a reference of it.

```
     <select type="text" className="form-control" name="filterOptions" id="filterOptions" onChange={this.optionsChange}>
            <option key="select" value="allValues">All Values</option>
            {this.renderFilterOptions(item)}
    </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You calling the function instead assigning it as a callback:

```
onChange={this.optionsChange}
```

Note that querying the DOM like this is an anti pattern and you should use `ref` as suggested in docs.

Also, you should use the `event` object of `onChange` instead.